# Laravel, how to get controller instance or classname in handle() inside App\Exceptions\Handler.php

Tags: laravel, exception, controller, httpexception

I have looked around and don't seem to find an answer or discussion regarding on this.

Is it possible to obtain the original controller's instance inside the "handle()" method in App\Exceptions\Handler.php?

I would like to know how to do this in order to know which controller the Exception happened from.

Thanks!

Comment: It is stored on an `Illuminate\Routing\Route` instance but it is protected and there's no defined getter for it. :/

Comment: Now that I've been using Laravel quite deeply, notice that there are many things that are quite inflexible. :-(  CodeIgniter used to be able to dig very deep and do many cool stuff.

Comment: is there any change on that?

Answer (score 0):

You have an **`$e->getTrace()`** which returns a stack trace of the exception object. 
But still you don't know in which index your controller is located unless you do a **dummy** search for it:

```
foreach ($e.getTrace() as $traceElement) {
   if (preg_match('/path\/to\/your\/Http\/Controllers\/(.*?)Controller/', $traceElement['class'])) {
         $controllerClass = traceElement['class'];
         $contrllerObject = new $controllerClass();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Sounds like a pretty hacky approach.  Might wanna see if there any alternatives first, though I appreciate the answer.